# How to check whether a type parameter is actually an interface

Tags: c#, .net

I have a generic function and I want to check whether the type parameter is an interface. Is there anyway to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A specific interface or any interface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`IsInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinterface.aspx) property of [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42892f65.aspx)..

```
public void DoCoolStuff<T>()
{
    if(typeof(T).IsInterface)
    {
        //TODO: Cool stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Like shooting fish in a barrel!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to **constrain** your generic method so that the type parameter can only be a type that implements some *specific* interface and nothing else, then you should do the following:

```
void YourGenericMethod<T>() where T : IYourInterface {
    // Do stuff. T is IYourInterface.
}
```

Comment: +1 I didn't think about it, but this might be the actual problem OP is trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

You can explicitly check the generic type parameter using `typeof` operator and `Type.IsInterface` property.

```
void MyMethod<T>() {
  bool isInterface = typeof(T).IsInterface;
}
```